# Solve $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}-\sqrt[3]{1-x}}$

Tags: limits

$\displaystyle {\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}{\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}-\sqrt[3]{1-x}}}=\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}{\frac{(\sqrt[3]{1+x}-\sqrt[3]{1-x})((\sqrt[3]{1+x})^2+(\sqrt[3]{1+x})(\sqrt[3]{1-x})+(\sqrt[3]{1-x})^2)}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}-\sqrt[3]{1-x}}}=3}$

but the right answer is 1.5

Comment: You've computed a different limit from the one asked of you. The function's numerator has square roots. But it's easily fixed with a square-roots-over-$2x$ factor.

Comment: Do you need to solve the problem without the L Hospital. I'm asking since you don't use it in your post

Comment: You can simplify the limit somewhat by writing$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}}{1-\sqrt[3]\frac{1-x}{1+x}}$$then substituting $y=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ to get the equivalent$$\lim_{y\to1}\frac{\sqrt y-1}{\sqrt[3]{y}-1}$$which is a little easier to rationalize.

Answer (score 4):

Given:
$$\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}-\sqrt[3]{1-x}}\right)$$
Apply L'Hopital's Rule
$$=\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+x}}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x}}}{\frac{1}{3\left(1+x\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}+\frac{1}{3\left(1-x\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}}\right)$$
**$\mathrm{Plug\:in\:the\:value}\:x=0$**
$$=\frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+0}}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-0}}}{\frac{1}{3\left(1+0\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}+\frac{1}{3\left(1-0\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}}$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

$\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}{\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}-\sqrt[3]{1-x}}}=\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}{\frac{(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x})(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})((\sqrt[3]{1+x})^2+(\sqrt[3]{1+x})(\sqrt[3]{1-x})+(\sqrt[3]{1-x})^2)}{(\sqrt[3]{1+x}-\sqrt[3]{1-x})(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})((\sqrt[3]{1+x})^2+(\sqrt[3]{1+x})(\sqrt[3]{1-x})+(\sqrt[3]{1-x})^2)}}=\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}{\frac {(2x)((\sqrt[3]{1+x})^2+(\sqrt[3]{1+x})(\sqrt[3]{1-x})+(\sqrt[3]{1-x})^2)}{(2x)(\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x})}}=\frac{3}{2}$

Answer (score 3):

Using asymptotic analysis and Taylor series we have as $x\to 0$:
$$
\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}\sim x+\mathcal O(x^2)=x(1+\mathcal O(x))
$$
and
$$
\sqrt[3]{1+x}-\sqrt[3]{1-x}\sim 2x/3+\mathcal O(x^2)=x(2/3+\mathcal O(x)).
$$
Thus
$$
\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}-\sqrt[3]{1-x}}=\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{1+\mathcal O(x)}{2/3+\mathcal O(x)}=\frac{3}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Using $u^2-v^2 = (u-v)(u+v)$ and $u^3-v^3 = (u-v)(u^2+uv+v^2)$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}-\sqrt[3]{1-x}}\\
=&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(\sqrt[6]{1+x})^3-(\sqrt[6]{1-x})^3}{(\sqrt[6]{1+x})^2-(\sqrt[6]{1-x})^2}\\
=&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt[6]{1+x}-\sqrt[6]{1-x}}{\sqrt[6]{1+x}-\sqrt[6]{1-x}}\cdot\frac{(\sqrt[6]{1+x})^2 + \sqrt[6]{1+x}\sqrt[6]{1-x}+(\sqrt[6]{1-x})^2}{\sqrt[6]{1+x}+\sqrt[6]{1-x}}\\
=& 1\cdot\frac{1+1+1}{1+1} = \frac{3}{2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

To make it look simpler, we can use the substitution $1+x = a$ and $1-x = b$ then simplify the expression $\frac{\sqrt a -\sqrt b}{\sqrt[3]a - \sqrt[3]b} $,
$$\dfrac{\sqrt a -\sqrt b}{\sqrt[3]a - \sqrt[3]b} \times \dfrac{\sqrt a + \sqrt b}{\sqrt a + \sqrt b} \times\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{a^2} + \sqrt[3]{b^2} +\sqrt[3]{ab}}{\sqrt[3]{a^2} + \sqrt[3]{b^2} +\sqrt[3]{ab}}$$$$= \dfrac{(\sqrt a - \sqrt b)(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)}{(\sqrt[3]a-\sqrt[3]b)(\sqrt[3]{a^2} + \sqrt[3]{b^2} +\sqrt[3]{ab})}\times\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{a^2} + \sqrt[3]{b^2} +\sqrt[3]{ab}}{\sqrt a+\sqrt b} = \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{a^2} + \sqrt[3]{b^2} +\sqrt[3]{ab}}{\sqrt a+\sqrt b}$$Hence we have
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}-\sqrt[3]{1-x}} = \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{(1+x)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(1-x)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(1+x)(1-x)}}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}=\frac32$$

Note that it is basically the same is Lion Heart's approach but you may find it less time consuming as I do.